# how to check list equality in Typescript Set data structure?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following Typescript code

```
const s = new Set<number[]>()
s.add([1, 2])
s.add([3, 4])
s.add([1, 2])
for (let t of s) {
  console.log(t)
} // prints [1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], but i would like the set not to have the [1, 2] duplicate
console.log(s.has([1, 2])) // prints false, i don't why it return false but I would like to return true
```

In python, having tuple automatically works

```
s = set()
s.add((1, 2)
s.add((1, 2)) # duplicate will not added
print((1, 2) in s) # True
```

How do I rewrite the Typescript code so set behaves in Python code? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s.has([1, 2])` returns false because of how JavaScript work.

```js
console.log([] === []);
```

will return false because it's not the same object.

---

My preferred way is to create `CustomSet` class that extends `Array<number[]>`, then implement your own `.add()` and `.has()`

```
class CustomSet extends Array<number[]> {
  add(arr: number[]) {
    if (!this.has(arr)) this.push(arr);
  }

  has(arr: number[]) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      if (this[i].every((v, j) => v === arr[j])) return true;
    }       
    return false;
  }
}

const s = new CustomSet()
s.add([1, 2])
s.add([3, 4])
s.add([1, 2])

console.log(t); // [[1, 2], [3, 4]] 
console.log(s.has([1, 2])); // true
console.log(s.has([1, 3])); // false
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCCuEAuB7AtgZQKZOlgHklgHYAmMAggE5VgCeAPMfGgEZZUDaAugHzQBvALAAoaNDClSACjA0AXNGZsOPAJSDR48QEsAZtGkBCJAAsdEAHSnIsmmo1mLlgA6JTdqmoDcW6AF9RPxsIT0Vldi5uDWExbT0UKkMQHGgdaABeaAAGbzToBmgnKxTiAHMzPJ0AamqYv200g2lizh1uSywANw46aWkugBo0jQz+LsyMrLkudodoKhx4KmIiqngsXzjxf0btBoWlleg9MBAITb9AkWvRYBRiZGgYLOIsAHc4RFRMHGk1URWSQyTgARmGACZooDLMDpJwAMzDAAs0JEQKk8PB0ChAJEdweEBQKUsIBQZWkEB8BMexKwpPJlOstjBkOi1JE91pJLJFKsISxwwR7O8QA)

Answer (score 1):

In python, sets rely on correct `__hash__` and `__eq__` implementations on items so that it can both

- avoid holding duplicate values
- check for membership of a value

However, in javascript, `Set` is comparatively less fully featured. Item membership is approximately based on whatever `===` does (with the caveat that `NaN` is considered the same as `NaN`, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for details). This means that for objects and **arrays**, it is using reference equality.

So, in your example, if we wanted to get behavior similar to the python example, we would need to be using the same references like so.

```
const s = new Set<number[]>();
const oneTwo = [1,2];
const threeFour = [3,4];
s.add(oneTwo);
s.add(threeFour);
s.add(oneTwo);
```

now, the set `s` only has two items (as expected), and `s.has(oneTwo)` is `true`.

However, it is probably inconvenient for you to use the same references everywhere.

--

One workaround to this issue is to just `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` everything that goes in/out of the Set. That way, it will check if the strings are equal (by value instead of by reference).

Another workaround to this issue is to just give up on JS sets altogether, and define some functions to operate on an array as if it were a set like so:

```
const areArraysEqual = (arrayA: number[], arrayB: number[]): boolean => {
    return arrayA.every((val, i) => val === arrayB[i]);
}

const insertIntoSet = (set: Array<number[]>, value: number[]): void => {
    const alreadyInSet = set.some((entry) => areArraysEqual(entry, value));
    if (!alreadyInSet) {
        set.push(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's doable as the *identical* arrays would be pointing to different instances. If you try this:

```
class FooSet<P> {
  public s = new Set<P>();

  public has(foo: P): boolean {
    for (let item of this.s.values()) {
      // Hacky way to check equality between arrays
      // Do not do this
      if (JSON.stringify(item) === JSON.stringify(foo)) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

  public add(foo: P) {
    let elementExists = this.has(foo);

    if (!elementExists) {
      this.s.add(foo);
    }
  }
}

const s = new FooSet<number[]>();

s.add([1, 2]);
s.add([2, 3]);
s.add([1, 2]);

for (let t of s.s) {
  console.log(t);
}

console.log(s.has([1, 2]));
```

you'd see how `set` behaves and how it asserts uniqueness. So to support your usecase you'd need to build some custom function wrapping the set

Answer (score 1):

You have already received some explanation about Set's.

I'd like to stick with pure types.

First of all, TS does not play well with mutable values. It just does not track mutations.

Second, please keep in mind that my **FIRST** example is not super useful in practice. I just want to give you more overview how TS works.

My second example is much useful and I believe you can use it, however I have never extended any built- in classes in practice. I believe **@T.J.Crowder** can give some advise.

In order to force TS do some checking, we should create simple wrapper for our `add` logic.

```js
const add = (set, value) => set.add(value)
```

Let's add some types:

```js
type Value = [number, number];
```

In order to allow TS track our `add` operations, let's add some cache.

```js
function add<S extends Set<Value> & { __cache?: any }, Vals extends Value>
    (set: S, value: [...Vals]) {
    return set.add(value)
}
```

Every time when `add` will be called, I will update `{ __cache?: any }`.

`{ __cache?: any } --> { __cache?: [] } --> { __cache?: [1,2] } --> { __cache?: [1,2] | [3,4] }` etc ....

Here is our main logic:

```js
type UpdateProp<T, Value> =
    T extends { __cache?: any[] }
    ? Set<Value> & Partial<Record<'__cache', T['__cache'] | Value>>
    : T & Partial<Record<'__cache', Value>>

type Check<T, Value> = T extends { __cache?: infer R } ? Value extends R ? 1 : 2 : 3

function add<
    S extends Set<Value> | Set<Value> & { __cache?: Value },
    Vals extends Value
>(set: S, value: [...Vals], ...flag: Check<S, Vals> extends 1 ? [never] : []): UpdateProp<S, Vals>
```

1. I expect that first argument will be always a `Set<Value>` (without cache) or  `Set<Value> & { __cache?: Value }` with cache.
2. `Vals extends Value` infers our array of two numbers
3. `UpdateProp<S, Vals>` smth similar to

```js
const updateProp=(obj,value)=>{
    return {
        ...obj,
        ['__cache']:value
    }
}
```

4. `...flag: Check<S, Vals> extends 1 ? [never] : []` - small validation trick. [Here, in my blog](https://catchts.com/validators) you can find full explanation

So, every time, when smbd call `add(set, [2,3])` `__cache` property will be updated/unionized.

Please keep in mind, `__cache` is optional, so don't worry, TS will not allow smth like that:`set.__cache`.

Full code:

```js
type Value = [number, number]


type UpdateProp<T, Value> =
    T extends { __cache?: any[] }
    ? Set<Value> & Partial<Record<'__cache', T['__cache'] | Value>>
    : T & Partial<Record<'__cache', Value>>


type Check<T, Value> = T extends { __cache?: infer R } ? Value extends R ? 1 : 2 : 3

function add<
    S extends Set<Value> | Set<Value> & { __cache?: Value },
    Vals extends Value
>(set: S, value: [...Vals], ...flag: Check<S, Vals> extends 1 ? [never] : []): UpdateProp<S, Vals>

function add<S extends Set<Value> & { __cache?: any }, Vals extends Value>
    (set: S, value: [...Vals]) {
    return set.add(value)
}

const result = add(new Set<Value>(), [1, 2]) // ok

const result2 = add(result, [3,4]) // ok

const result3 = add(result2, [3,4]) // expected error

const result4 = add(result2, [4,3]) // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK7QLxQNoDskFsBGEATgDRQ4HEC6AUHaJFAKpgAmcwEACkQPZgAeACpl4yCAD4oqGlDlQhUCAA9OWVgGcoAbygB9PQGM4hgBYQA-AC4ocLCAxUoAX1nyLUAMoRgAsSikAMiguOCJgAEtEAQAlCENeIlYBAHIDYzMIFLIhDDSjE3MUpwAfWEQAiTc5G0Vg0PCohFj4xOT8jKLRCskq%20nBoAGFzQwBrYW7xKXRFFTVNHX0CzOsoCKwAM2IoGJcoD39oOYh1LV2PAEYoGwAma6gAZjoNpCxDSN4sW1Zk6q8lVQnBbeXyHKRlEF%20HpBRbpQqWGyHFwkP5iLTHU7lcQ0CQACg0PhsnjIADcejYMAA6aloqhkamUjYIOAAcxsw3i42JWI0UgxCyuHmwEBJ1HujgAlDYWOxODx%20AJuWi%20i83h8vnAfoqAfMtJCwVBgro4SsbHYQMieTqgVowX98YSvKTyZgGbSJTo-kQfEgiF8CcBKZrWLiyeIJTRXDQElgNMAoN6NEgEPH0MHcVgIAB3Lw%20KFTXESsgYC5kG5UD0AekrUF4ozoMbjCYgSZTdzTP1xieTwGLDxIABYK1Bq7X69HPk3uymHtJviHp8Abn3B8PRypIO8IKwlEQ%20EQG5P44uB3P04vl5gByQHmua3WgA)

If you still want to use `Set` in normal way, like all people ))

you can extend `Set` class:

```js
class MySet<T extends [number, number]> extends Set<T>{
    override add(val: T) {
        const [x, y] = val
        const keys = [...this.keys()];
        const exists = keys.findIndex(([a, b]) => a === x && b === y)
        if (exists === -1) {
            return this
        }

        super.add(val)
        return this
    }
}
```

I have used `override` keyword which is new in TS 4.3. Feel free to get rid of it if you have lower version of TS

[Playground 2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.0-beta#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBlApgFwDwBVrIB6uQDsATGAbUIFcBbAI2QCcAaaKuxgXQD4d8jToKDJi4BvAFDQp0APYA3RgwCWxZNDDFiACjlgQALmiYAlNAnSL0YDMIRU0MrhbwO0ALzRdISZanXb9gDWyPAwHmQAdFGoABZKEBHBoVrGHADcPr7%20drzxqGHQSQkAZkokAJIkeFpaZGAstBymbjxg7m4euNAAZN3QtO0e8MaZlkrF0Fp4eWEd0AC0AIym5r6WDGiUDITQsfGjFgC%204gfSEJQADowRGtpeI2vQG6hbO3sQo8eHQA)